# How to activate a function for sending reminder emails from data collected from a form?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, jinja2

I am still new to Python. I am working on a code that collects data from a form including datetime object and stores on a database and then returns a success page.

My Problem and this is where i'm stuck is how to send reminder emails at certain intervals to specified emails based on the datetime value entered in the form if the datetime entered in the form is sometime in the future. reminders can automatically be sent at two days interval until the datetime.

I have created the send email function and it works fine. I send emails to specified emails when a data is submitted. but my problem is how do I send reminder emails based on the date entered in the form.

I need help please.

I have tried creating a while loop that checks if the current date and time is equal to the date entered in the form. but this while loop will prevent the form from sending data to the database since it has to wait until the while loop is exited.

I need ideas on how to achieve this

Here is the code that sends email automatically when a data is entered in the database.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import redirect
import jinja2
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
from send_email import send_email

@app.route("/success", methods=['POST'])
def success():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        company=request.form["companyname"]
        title=request.form["ttitle"]
        tnumber=request.form["tnumber"]
        ttype=request.form["ttype"]
        tstatus=request.form["tstatus"]
        tduedate=request.form["tduedate"]
        cperson=request.form["cperson"]
        cpersonemail=request.form["cpersonemail"]
        cpersonno=request.form["cpersonnumber"]
        comments=request.form["comments"]
        send_email(tnumber, company)
        data=Data(company, title, tnumber,ttype,tstatus,tduedate,cperson,cpersonemail, cpersonno, comments)
        db.session.add(data)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("success.html")
```

I need someone to guide me on how i can send out reminders when this success() method is executed based on the tduedate entered in the form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to check Celery - http://www.celeryproject.org
It is a task queue management package and will take care of scheduling and triggering a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Advanced Python Scheduler might be more appropriate for your use case https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()
```

Then in your view

```py
from apscheduler.triggers.date import DateTrigger

@app.route("/success", methods=['POST'])
def success():
    ...
    scheduler.add_job(
        send_email, DateTrigger(tduedate), args=(tnumber, company)
    )
```

You'll want to consider a persistent jobstore if scheduled jobs need to persist when the application stops running.